# JavaScript - from alert to function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new on my quest for learning JavaScript(only two weeks) so be nice and surprised how far I got.

What I’m trying to do is hit a button and the button will evoke a random image or div to come to the front. I as you see I use the z-index by moving elements from back to front.

I have got far enough to create an alert that tells me it does find the random function just cant get it to activate this function (the changeCombined functions do work fine when I assign it to a button but just can’t get the getImage to run).

I’m unsure if it is possible, and I know there might be a hundred better ways to do this but one step at a time.

```
function changeZIndex(i,id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.zIndex=i;
};

var changeCombined1 = function() {
    changeZIndex(-5,"scene1");
    changeZIndex(5,"scene2");
};  

var changeCombined2 = function() {
    changeZIndex(-5,"scene2");
    changeZIndex(5,"scene1");
};

function get_random(){
    var ranNum= Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
    return ranNum;
}

function getImage(){
    var whichImage=get_random();
    var image=new Array()
    image[0]=changeCombined2;
    image[1]=changeCombined1;

    alert(quote[whichImage]);
}
```

Comment: You aren't actually ever calling the function

Comment: What is your intention with the `image` array within `getImage()`? There's no point in running both of `changeCombined1` and `changeCombined2` since they update the same elements. And where is the array `quote` (used in `alert(quote[whichImage])`) defined?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function changeZIndex(i,id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.zIndex=i;
};

function getImage(){
    var whichImage=Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
    var image=new Array()
    image[0]=function() {
        changeZIndex(-5,"scene2");
        changeZIndex(5,"scene1");
    };
    image[1]=function() {
        changeZIndex(-5,"scene1");
        changeZIndex(5,"scene2");
    };

    image[whichimage]();

    alert(quote[whichImage]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the `changeCombined()` functions at all.

If you are trying to *call* the functions, you have to use `()`

```
image[0]=changeCombined2();
image[1]=changeCombined1();
```

What you have just the functions themselves to `image[0]` and `image[1]`. 
So after

```
x = changeCombined2;
```

`x` will hold a reference to the `changeCombined2` *function itself*. So now if you say `x()` (or in your case `image[0]()`), it will *call* `changeCombined2`.

`()` will call the functions and will put the return value of the function into the array elements.

Note: since the functions do not explicitly return anything, `image[0]` and `image[1]` will hold `undefined`.

Comment: ...except `changeCombined1()` and `changeCombined2()` don't return anything useful...

Comment: @Cory - Sure they do, they return `undefined`.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Psych! Edited comment.

Answer (score 0):

To invoke a function you should use either [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) methods.

Have you tried `image[whichImage].apply(undefined)` instead of your `alert` ?

Comment: That seems an overly complex way of saying `image[whichImage]()`, especially if you're just going to pass in `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help to get past my road block, the rookie mistake of not calling my funcions was the biggest issue. I was able montage the comments to create this version that works as expected.

```
function changeZIndex(i,id) { 
    document.getElementById(id).style.zIndex=i;}; 

function getImage(){ 
    var whichImage=Math.floor(Math.random()*2); 

    var image=new Array() 

    image[0]=function() { 
    changeZIndex(-5,"scene2"); 
    changeZIndex(5,"scene1"); 
    }; 

    image[1]=function() { 
    changeZIndex(-5,"scene1"); 
    changeZIndex(5,"scene2"); 
    }; 

    image[whichImage].apply(undefined);};
```